# VHDL/GHDL: Why does port name hide entity?

Tags: warnings, vhdl, ghdl

I'm using GHDL v3.0.0 as a VHDL simulator, but I'm getting a warning I don't understand

In short, with this entity:

```
entity GSR is
    port ( gsr: in std_ulogic);
end GSR;
```

I get this warning:

```
mock.vhd:5:16:warning: declaration of "gsr" hides entity "gsr" [-Whide]
        port ( gsr: in std_ulogic);
               ^
```

Full details...
In my simulation I need to mock an entity (so entity name and port names must match the third party library entity I'm mocking).

This is in my mock.vhd file:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity GSR is
    port ( gsr: in std_ulogic);
end GSR;

architecture sim of GSR is
begin
end sim;
```

To show the problem I've created a very cut-down example of a testbench.vhd:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity testbench is
end testbench;

architecture sim of testbench is
    signal resetn : std_logic := '0';
begin
  
  gsr_inst: entity work.GSR port map (gsr => resetn);
  
  process
  begin
    wait;
  end process;
  
end sim;
```

The warning comes when I analyse:

```
steven@Stevens-Laptop gsr % ghdl  -a mock.vhd testbench.vhd
mock.vhd:5:16:warning: declaration of "gsr" hides entity "gsr" [-Whide]
        port ( gsr: in std_ulogic);
               ^
```

I don't see a circumstance where the port gsr can hide the entity GSR, and hence why is this a warning?  An example or two of when this could cause a problem would help my understanding.

I think I've described everything that's relevant the problem and what I've done above. I've search for the warning text on-line but found nothing that seems relevant, or maybe I didn't understand it.

Comment: I asked sometimes a similar question, see [here](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/issues/2501)

Comment: @MatthiasSchweikart I see a similarity but I think your example is different. Your procedure signals are hiding the ports, not an entity.

Comment: *...why is this a warning?* [Warning messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7jGS.jpg) serve as prompts pointing out potential errors. A warning an error and a related error message together can provide a specific cause. Here while there are no analysis warnings specified in the standard there's likewise no requirement to speculate on a cause of an error either. Without an error such a warning could be disregarded. ghdl can also disable such warnings on the command line (`ghdl -a --warn-no-hide mock.vhdl`). Try it while requiring the entity name be directly visible.

Answer (score 0):

VHDL does not differentiate identifiers by their case:

> **15.4.2 Basic identifiers**
>
> [...] Basic identifiers differing only in the use of corresponding uppercase
> and lowercase letters are considered the same.

So your port `gsr` hides the entity `GSR`.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain *Why does port name hide entity?*. IEEE Std 1076-2002 shows the addition of the definition of *root declarative region* which was always there just not described. A root declarative region is required to make multiple primary units in a design file work by allowing innermost declarative regions to be purged from the 'symbol table'. during analysis. The entity declaration occurs in an outer declarative region and is hidden by homograph port signal declaration in the inner declarative region associated with the entity declaration itself.

Comment: The scope of the entity declaration extending from the beginning of the entity declaration allows secondary design units (here an architecture) to be associated with the entity declaration in the same declarative region. -1993 was mainly about formalizing the VHDL language, it wasn't until the -2000 standard release process that someone threw the root declarative region into the mix (along with *library declarative region*).  Changes for these were deferred until -2002 as likely not quite complete or a distraction to a hurried release of IEEE Std 1076-2000.